# Problem Using Python CAN with Pi Can 2 Hat

Tags: python, pi-3b+, can-bus

I hope to find some answers here regarding a program of mine that doesnt seem to work! It is a modified version from https://rb.gy/blrhk . I am using the RPi in conjunction with an arduno uno with a neo 6m gps connected to it. The RPi reads the serial port of the arduino and every time there is a new message (i.e the gps has refreshed from the arduino) the RPi sends a can bus message asking for specific OBD parameters via the cun bus hat such as RPM etc etc. The problem I'm facing is that the philosophy of the program is based on one thread sending can bus messages and another receiving them. This brings problems with timing as I want to capture the time difference between each frame.(The threads as by nature are not time synced?). So I tried to modify the program even more to run on one thread, sending and receiving. The problem here is that I cant read anything that I have requested from the ECU, as if the bus can only send OR receive on one thread!
Here is the WORKING code with two threads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from this import d
import serial

import board

import busio

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

import os

import can

import string

import sys

from threading import Thread

import urllib.request

index=0

grand=0

total_maf=0

maf_previ=0



def get_user():

    global user

    user = input("PLEASE ENTER USER CODE:\n")

    return True

def connect(host='http://google.com'):

    try:

        urllib.request.urlopen(host) 

        return True

    except:

        return False

while True:

    if connect() and get_user():

        index=1

        print("CONNECTED")

    else:

        print("Not Ready YET")

        time.sleep(1)

    while index==1:

        from datetime import datetime
        from datetime import timedelta

        timog=datetime.now()

        global ln

        ln=datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y___%H-%M-%S')

        index=0

        start_time=time.time()

        led = 22

        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

        GPIO.setwarnings(False)

        GPIO.setup(led,GPIO.OUT)

        GPIO.output(led,True)

        GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)

        MAF_SENSOR             = 0x10

        INTAKE_AIR_TEMPERATURE = 0x0F

        ENGINE_RPM             = 0x0C

        ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP    = 0x05

        VEHICLE_SPEED          = 0x0D

        PID_REQUEST            = 0x7DF

        PID_REPLY              = 0x7E8

        os.mkdir("/home/paulbts/CapturesNH/%s" % ln)

        file=open("/home/paulbts/CapturesNH/%s/DATAFRAMES.txt" % ln ,"a")

        os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000")

        time.sleep(0.1)

        os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 txqueuelen 1000")

        print('Ready')

        try:

            bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='socketcan', channel='can0')

        except OSError:

            print('Cannot find PiCAN board.')

            GPIO.output(led,False)

            exit()





          

        def can_rx_task():
            timog=datetime.now()
            global maf_previ
            global total_maf
            global sns
            global speed
            global rpm
            global speedprev
            sns=0
            speed=0
            rpm=0
            speedprev=0
            initime=timedelta(microseconds=0)
            initimemaf=timedelta(microseconds=0)
            while True:

                message = bus.recv()

                


                if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == ENGINE_RPM:

                    c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)

                    s=''

                    for i in range(message.dlc ):

                        s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])

                    rpm = round(((message.data[3]*256) + message.data[4])/4)
                    file.write(str(user)+",")
                    if rpm>0 and rpm<5000:
                        file.write(str(rpm)+",")
                        if rpm>800:

                            file.write("0,")

                        else:

                            file.write("1,")




                

                if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == VEHICLE_SPEED:
                    ts=datetime.now()

                    c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)

                    s=''

                    for i in range(message.dlc ):

                        s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])

                    speed = message.data[3]
                    if speed>-1 and speed<200:
                        file.write(str(speed)+",")
                        deltas=ts-initime
                        file.write(str(deltas)+",")
                        if speed==0:
                            file.write("Stopped,")
                        if speed>0:
                            file.write("Moving,")
                        if speed<=50:

                            file.write("Urban,")
                        if speed<=90 and speed>50:

                            file.write("Non_Urban,")
                        if speed<=130 and speed>90:

                            file.write("Motorway,")
                        if speed>130:
                            file.write("Over_Speed_Limit,")
                        if speed==0 and rpm<850 and speedprev!=speed:
                            sns=sns+1
                        file.write(str(sns)+",")
                        speedprev=speed
                        initime=ts
                        print(str(speed))

                

                if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == INTAKE_AIR_TEMPERATURE:

                    c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)

                    s=''

                    for i in range(message.dlc ):

                        s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])

                    airtemperature = message.data[3]-40

                    if airtemperature>-40 and airtemperature<215:
                        file.write(str(airtemperature)+",")

                        print(str(airtemperature))

                    

                if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP:

                    c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)

                    s=''

                    for i in range(message.dlc ):

                        s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])

                    temperature = message.data[3] - 40

                    if temperature>-40 and temperature<215:
                        file.write(str(temperature)+",")

                    

                if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == MAF_SENSOR:
                    tsmaf=datetime.now()
                    c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)

                    s=''

                    for i in range(message.dlc ):

                        s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])

                    maf = round(((message.data[3]*256) + message.data[4])/100)

                    if maf>0.0 and maf<100.0:
                        file.write(str(maf)+",")
                        delta=tsmaf-initimemaf

                        file.write(str(delta)+",")

                        deltamaf=0.5*(maf+maf_previ)

                        file.write(str(deltamaf)+",")

                        maf_previ=maf
                        initimemaf=tsmaf

                        #total_maf=(deltamaf*delta)

                        #file.write(str(total_maf)+",")
                
                if rpm>3000:
                    

                    time.sleep(0.5)

                    GPIO.output(led,False)

                    file.close()

                    os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 down")

                    time.sleep(0.5)

                    print('\n\rKeyboard interrtupt')

                    exit()
                    raise Exception()
                if grand==1:

                    exit()

                

                

                



        t = Thread(target = can_rx_task)

        t.start()

        



        try:

            

            if __name__ == '__main__' and connect():

                ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)

                ser.reset_input_buffer()

                





            while True:

                if ser.in_waiting > 0:

                    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8',errors="replace").rstrip()+"\n"

                    file.write(line)

                    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,ENGINE_RPM,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],is_extended_id=False)

                    bus.send(msg)

                    time.sleep(0.01)

                    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,VEHICLE_SPEED,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],is_extended_id=False)

                    bus.send(msg)

                    time.sleep(0.01)

                    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,INTAKE_AIR_TEMPERATURE,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],is_extended_id=False)

                    bus.send(msg)

                    time.sleep(0.01)

                    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],is_extended_id=False)

                    bus.send(msg)

                    time.sleep(0.01)

                    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,MAF_SENSOR,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],is_extended_id=False)

                    bus.send(msg)

                    print(line)

                    print(index)

                    

                    index+=1

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            #Catch keyboard interrupt

            grand=1

            time.sleep(0.5)

            GPIO.output(led,False)

            file.close()

            os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 down")

            time.sleep(0.5)

            print('\n\rKeyboard interrtupt')

            exit()
```

and here is the SINGLE threaded code that doesnt work!:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import serial
import board
import busio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import can
import string
import sys
import urllib.request
from threading import Thread
from this import d

index=0
grand=0
total_maf=0
maf_previ=0



def get_user():

    global user

    user = input("PLEASE ENTER USER CODE:\n")

    return True

def connect(host='http://google.com'):

    try:

        urllib.request.urlopen(host) 

        return True

    except:

        return False

while True:

    if connect() and get_user():

        index=1

        print("CONNECTED")

    else:

        print("Not Ready YET")

        time.sleep(1)

    while index==1:  #After User has been registered

        from datetime import datetime
        from datetime import timedelta

        timog=datetime.now()

        global ln

        ln=datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y___%H-%M-%S')

        index=0

        start_time=time.time()

        led = 22

        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

        GPIO.setwarnings(False)

        GPIO.setup(led,GPIO.OUT)

        GPIO.output(led,True)

        GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)

        MAF_SENSOR             = 0x10

        INTAKE_AIR_TEMPERATURE = 0x0F

        ENGINE_RPM             = 0x0C

        ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP    = 0x05

        VEHICLE_SPEED          = 0x0D

        PID_REQUEST            = 0x7DF

        PID_REPLY              = 0x7E8

        os.mkdir("/home/paulbts/CapturesNH/%s" % ln)

        file=open("/home/paulbts/CapturesNH/%s/DATAFRAMES.txt" % ln ,"a")

        os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000")

        time.sleep(0.1)

        os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 txqueuelen 1000")

        print('Ready')

        try:

            bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='socketcan', channel='can0')

        except OSError:

            print('Cannot find PiCAN board.')

            GPIO.output(led,False)

            exit()


        try:

            if __name__ == '__main__' and connect():

                ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=1)

                ser.reset_input_buffer()


            while True:
                timog=datetime.now()
                global maf_previ
                global total_maf
                global sns
                global speed
                global rpm
                global speedprev
                sns=0
                speed=0
                rpm=0
                speedprev=0
                initime=timedelta(microseconds=0)
                initimemaf=timedelta(microseconds=0)
                if ser.in_waiting > 0:

                    line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8',errors="replace").rstrip()+"\n"

                    file.write(line)

                    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,ENGINE_RPM,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],is_extended_id=False)

                    bus.send(msg)

                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    message = bus.recv()
                    if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == ENGINE_RPM:

                        c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)

                        s=''

                        for i in range(message.dlc ):

                            s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])

                        rpm = round(((message.data[3]*256) + message.data[4])/4)
                        file.write(str(user)+",")
                        if rpm>0 and rpm<5000:
                            file.write(str(rpm)+",")
                            if rpm>800:

                                file.write("0,")

                            else:

                                file.write("1,")

                    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,VEHICLE_SPEED,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],is_extended_id=False)

                    bus.send(msg)

                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    message = bus.recv()
                    if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == VEHICLE_SPEED:
                        ts=datetime.now()

                        c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)

                        s=''

                        for i in range(message.dlc ):

                            s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])

                        speed = message.data[3]
                        if speed>-1 and speed<200:
                            file.write(str(speed)+",")
                            deltas=ts-initime
                            file.write(str(deltas)+",")
                            if speed==0:
                                file.write("Stopped,")
                            if speed>0:
                                file.write("Moving,")
                            if speed<=50:

                                file.write("Urban,")
                            if speed<=90 and speed>50:

                                file.write("Non_Urban,")
                            if speed<=130 and speed>90:

                                file.write("Motorway,")
                            if speed>130:
                                file.write("Over_Speed_Limit,")
                            if speed==0 and rpm<850 and speedprev!=speed:
                                sns=sns+1
                            file.write(str(sns)+",")
                            speedprev=speed
                            initime=ts
                            print(str(speed))

                    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,INTAKE_AIR_TEMPERATURE,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],is_extended_id=False)

                    bus.send(msg)

                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    message=bus.recv()
                    if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == INTAKE_AIR_TEMPERATURE:

                        c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)

                        s=''

                        for i in range(message.dlc ):

                            s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])

                        airtemperature = message.data[3]-40

                        if airtemperature>-40 and airtemperature<215:
                            file.write(str(airtemperature)+",")

                            print(str(airtemperature))
                    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],is_extended_id=False)

                    bus.send(msg)

                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    message=bus.recv()
                    if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == ENGINE_COOLANT_TEMP:

                        c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)

                        s=''

                        for i in range(message.dlc ):

                            s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])

                        temperature = message.data[3] - 40

                        if temperature>-40 and temperature<215:
                            file.write(str(temperature)+",")
                    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=PID_REQUEST,data=[0x02,0x01,MAF_SENSOR,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00],is_extended_id=False)

                    bus.send(msg)
                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    message=bus.recv()
                    if message.arbitration_id == PID_REPLY and message.data[2] == MAF_SENSOR:
                        tsmaf=datetime.now()
                        c = '{0:f} {1:x} {2:x} '.format(message.timestamp, message.arbitration_id, message.dlc)

                        s=''

                        for i in range(message.dlc ):

                            s +=  '{0:x} '.format(message.data[i])

                        maf = round(((message.data[3]*256) + message.data[4])/100)

                        if maf>0.0 and maf<100.0:
                            file.write(str(maf)+",")
                            delta=tsmaf-initimemaf
                            file.write(str(delta)+",")
                            deltamaf=0.5*(maf+maf_previ)
                            file.write(str(deltamaf)+",")
                            maf_previ=maf
                            initimemaf=tsmaf
                            #total_maf=(deltamaf*delta)
                            #file.write(str(total_maf)+",")

                    if rpm>3000:
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        GPIO.output(led,False)
                        file.close()
                        os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 down")
                        time.sleep(0.5)
                        print('\n\rKeyboard interrtupt')
                        exit()
                        raise Exception()
                    print(line)
                    print(index)
                    index+=1

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            #Catch keyboard interrupt
            grand=1
            time.sleep(0.5)
            GPIO.output(led,False)
            file.close()
            os.system("sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 down")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print('\n\rKeyboard interrtupt')
            exit()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why all the blank lines in your code - it just makes it hard to read. Your text on the other hand could do with some paragraphs.